# How to enable default master kubelet cadvisor to collect all system services performance metrics also..?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, kubelet, cadvisor

I have a VM on which k8s v1.16.2 is deployed and on top of it prometheus and grafana services running. On grafana dashboard i am able to see all containers and pods performance metrics but for system services only docker and kubelet, Why its not showing other services metrics which are running directly on machine.

**Is there any configurations by default kubelet sets to cadvisor which restricts collecting system service metrics..?** 
*because with kubelet version v1.13.1 i was able to see system services metrics.*

**How can i get all service metrics which runs under system.slice through cadvisor of kubelet..?**

Verified through :

- Hitting directly Prometheus endpoints.
- Tried directly cadvisor endpoint(k8s exposed endpoint) : /api/v1/nodes/HOSTNAME/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

on both endpoints results i am not seeing any system service metrics except docker and kubelet

**Version:**

- Docker: 18.09.6,
- Kubelet: v1.16.2,
- CGroup Driver: systemd

**Below is Prometheus Configuration:**

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [id]
    separator: ;
    regex: ^/machine\.slice/machine-rkt\\x2d([^\\]+)\\.+/([^/]+)\.service$
    target_label: rkt_container_name
    replacement: ${2}-${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [id]
    separator: ;
    regex: ^/system\.slice/(.+)\.service$
    target_label: systemd_service_name
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
```

Comment: Could you provide some of your configuration? In Kubernetes 1.16 there was many `apiVersion` changes. It stopped working just after you upgraded your Kubernetes and docker version?

Answer (score 0):

Cadvisor only knows about containers run through the same underlying system as your CRI plugin. I’m guessing that is no longer the case since I see stuff about systemd and rkt in there?

Comment: I didn't configure/deploy cadvisor manually, it's the one which comes default with kubelet which directly runs on host machine. As i mentioned, it was working when i was using kubelet 1.13.1 but in 1.16.1 its not.